# PageReference giving error while getContentAsPDF()

Tags: community, pagereference

I am having a custom button which is calling a static method.

In this method I am getting content in PDF form by using `getContentAsPDF()` method.

This code works fine if i am hard coding the URL

```
 webService static string docusignSendContractUsing( string contractAmendmentId){enter image description here
......
PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference( 'https://c.cs12.visual.force.com/apex/PreviewContractPdfTemplate?Id=a1FV0000001k5nDMAQ' +  '&isPreview=false');
Blob body = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();    
system.debug('##'+body);
......
}
```

But when i take the base URL like

```
    webService static string docusignSendContractUsing( string contractAmendmentId){
......
String baseUrl=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference(baseUrl +'/apex/PreviewContractPdfTemplate?Id=a1FV0000001k5nDMAQ' +  '&isPreview=false');
Blob body = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();    
system.debug('##'+body);
......
}
```

I am getting an error 
[image]

> Internal Salesforce.com Error. Please check valid mark up error

Comment: Try setting your `PageReference` equal to `Page.PreviewContractPdfTemplate` and then on that reference call `getParameters().put('Id', someId')` and the same thing with `isPreview`.

Comment: I tried for this 

String baseUrl=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference(baseUrl + '/apex/PreviewContractPdfTemplate');
pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', 'a1FV0000001k5nDMAQ');
pdfPage.getParameters().put('isPreview', 'false');
Blob body = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF(); 

but facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() call will return the non-Visualforce domain e.g. https://cs12.salesforce.com rather than the Visualforce domain e.g. https://c.cs12.visual.force.com that is required to access the page. When accessing a page from the browser, the browser is redirected to the correct domain - so either form works - but that doesn't happen when accessing a page on the server side.

I don't know of a clean solution to this problem - see various utilities posted in the answers to [Retrieve salesforce instance URL instead of visualforce instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369653/retrieve-salesforce-instance-url-instead-of-visualforce-instance) that convert the domain.